# Learning Python the Hard Way terminal setup

Tags: python, powershell, terminal

So I'm trying to setup the terminal in conjunction with Notepad++ and I'm a little confused. I've managed to download Python 2.7 and load it up in Powershell but I don't really know where to go from there. Do I even need to use a terminal? I know it says you can't use IDLE but it would be a lot easier. If anyone can guide me through getting the right setup to go on with the book I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I'd forget about Powershell and just use `cmd.exe` -- I think there's something about doing that in an appendix. That means all you need to do next is download and install an editor like Notepad++. I believe there's an extension for it that will run the current file as a Python program using the Python you have installed. After installing the editor you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to get python running in the powershell following the [Exercice 0](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html), and you read the "Warning For Beginners" section, you can proceed to Exercice 1.

Why do they recommend that setup? Notepad++ is on Windows a powerful text editor very similar to other text editors, so you will soon get familiar with it. You will need to save your scripts in files and type a special line in the powershell to run and test them. That way you will get accustomed to running programs with arguments and if you make a failure, you can edit your code, save it and run it again.

In IDLE, you are already in a Python environment, so you cannot give arguments to your program inside it (actually you can but it's complex). You can also get an editor, save your file and run the script but also here it's a harder and less obvious way than Notepad++. When you get comfortable with the environment in that book you may change to get something that suits better your way of doing.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what to do now though.